# nested routeing of private route react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
const App = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = useRecoilValue(isLoggedInState)
    const setCustomers = useSetRecoilState(customersState);
    const setSchedules = useSetRecoilState(scheduleState);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(isLoggedIn) {
            setCustomers(customers);
            setSchedules(schedules);
        }
    },[isLoggedIn, setCustomers, setSchedules])
    return <div className="App">
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute exact={true} path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/" component={MainApp} />
        </Switch>
    </div>;
}

const Private = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const isLoggedIn = useRecoilValue(isLoggedInState);
    return <Route {...rest}
    render={props => {
        return isLoggedIn
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location}}}/>
    }}/>
};

const MainApp = () => {
    let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
    return <>
        <header>
            <Link exact to={path} activeClassName="active-tab">Schedule Today</Link>
            <Link exact to={`${path}customer`} activeClassName="active-tab">Customers</Link>
        </header>
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path={url} component={Schedules}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact={true} path={`${url}customer`} component={Customers}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact={true} path={`${url}customer/:id`} component={CustomerInfo}/>
        </Switch>
    </>;
};
```

over react router dom documentation, nested need to be under the same path.
I try to build web application has private and public routing.
under the private route want to create nested routing.
after login go to the component I want but when click on the customer tab is not recognized Why?
also, the header is removed.

Comment: Do not use exact when you have nested routing: `<PrivateRoute path="/" component={MainApp} />`

Comment: thanks :),
How did I not get over it